# Startup Preview Server Listener

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

My Eclipse is waiting for startup preview server listener to complete, I have restarted my Eclipse and deleted the server/conf folder as well. That did not help, please suggest what is the permanent way to resolve this issue.

I also tried related Stackoverflow links but did not help much.

Comment: Kill the Java process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.

1. Open Task Manager
2. Under the Processes tab look out for any process's which have image name as `java` or `javaw`
3. Kill these process's and try again.

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!